# Excel matching separate first and last name columns to another sheet containing a combined "last, first name" column.

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have searched and tried various VLOOKUP and MATCH formulas for matching separate first and last name columns to another sheet containing a combined "last, first name" column.  I'm new to excel formulas like this.

Sheet 1
Column A is Last Name
Column B is First Name

Sheet 2
Column G is Last Name, First Name
Also in Column H there is an additional Last Name, First Name that I'd like to search for matches also if possible.

I'd like to find which names from Sheet 1 match data on Sheet 2.

Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

You should always post the code that you tried so that people don't feel like they're just doing your work for you. The following assumes you have no excess white-space in any cell and your letter casing matches between data. It also assumes that your second sheet is, indeed, named "Sheet 2". This belongs in the first row of your lookup column on Sheet 1

```
=IF(AND(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A1&", "&B1,Sheet2!G:G,1,FALSE)),ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A1&", "&B1,'Sheet 2'!H:H,1,FALSE))),"NO MATCH",IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A1&", "&B1,'Sheet 2'!G:G,1,FALSE)),"MATCH IN COL H","MATCH IN COL G"))
```

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in the formula a second ago, it will work now.

Comment: Thank You so much - this worked great too.  Sorry about not posting previous code attempts.  Thank you for this it really helped!

Comment: If it helped, how about selecting it as best answer? Or just selecting a best answer... the other answer is good, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `COUNTIF` you can search both columns in one go, e,g. this formula in sheet1 C2 copied down

`=IF(COUNTIF(Sheet2!G:H,A2&", "&B2),"Match","No Match")`